# Websql Database insert data into one table not another?

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, web-sql

Hello Friend I Face a Strange Problem. I developing the PHP  Desktop Application,

And I  am using the websql Database.When I submitted the Data into users table

Data Submitted  Successfully.But When I submitted to another Table Data is not

Submitted.table Structure is same.I don't Know what to do for this?

Please help.  Here is my code...

```
<?php

session_start();
//$WindowUser = getenv('username');
//$myPDO = new PDO("sqlite:C:/Users/".$WindowUser."/Desktop/barber_shop/webcache/databases/http_127.0.0.1_51915/2");
include("../sqlitePhpDatabase/sqlitePhpDatabase.php");   
$store_name = $_POST['store_name'];
$street = $_POST['street'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$location_id = $_POST['location_id'];

 $sth = $myPDO->exec("INSERT INTO bs_stores(store_name,street, status,location_id)VALUES('store_name','$street','$status','$location_id')");
//$sth = $myPDO->exec("INSERT INTO bs_locations(city)VALUES('rere')");
if(isset($sth) && !empty($sth))
{
    echo "done";    
}
else
{
    echo "data is not submiting";   
}   ?>
```

Comment: please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for copy all data :-

```
INSERT INTO tab1 SELECT * FROM tab2;
```

or this for copy selected data:-

```
INSERT INTO tab1
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       NULL
  FROM tab2
```